# Get value using forwardref onclick on checkbox in react hook form DataTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datatable, react-hooks

In React hook form I am struggling with checked all on click on single checkbox in DataTable.

Here is checked all function using forwardRef

```
const BootstrapCheckbox = forwardRef(({ onClick, ...rest }, ref) => ( 
  <div className='custom-control custom-checkbox'>
    <input type='checkbox' className='custom-control-input' ref={ref} {...rest} />
    <label className='custom-control-label' onClick={onClick} />
  </div>
))
```

Here is DataTable code where BootstrapCheckbox is calling

```
<DataTable
 noHeader
 selectableRows
 pagination
 paginationServer
 columns={advSearchColumns} 
 className='react-dataTable'
 sortIcon={<ChevronDown size={10} />}
 paginationComponent={CustomPagination}
 data={dataToRender()} 
 selectableRowsComponent={BootstrapCheckbox}
/>
```

I don't know how to get ref value or set the ref or get something like all rows ids,
Here is DataTable Row

```
const advSearchColumns = [
 
  {
    name: 'status',
    selector: 'status',
    maxWidth: '10px',
    ignoreRowClick: true,
    cell: row => <CustomInput type='switch' onClick={(e) => handleswitchStatus(row.id, +e.target.checked)}  id={row.id}  name='status' inline defaultChecked={row.is_active} />
  },
  {
    name: 'Name',
    selector: 'name',
    sortable: true,
    minWidth: '150px'
  } 
]
```

Any Help from anyone ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

```
// This will select the rows and return them as an array
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([])

....

const handleChange = (state) => setSelectedRows(state.selectedRows)

......

<DataTable
    noHeader
    selectableRows
    pagination
    paginationServer
    columns={advSearchColumns} 
    className='react-dataTable'
    sortIcon={<ChevronDown size={10} />}
    paginationComponent={CustomPagination}
    data={dataToRender()} 
    selectableRowsComponent={BootstrapCheckbox}
    onSelectedRowsChange={handleChange} // add this
/>
```